# How to "seed" a DFS replication that is already on-going

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs-r

There are many tutorials online that explain how to pre-seed a brand new replication set-up. But is there a proper way to "speed up" an existing replication without taking it down?

We have an existing DFSR set-up between 2 continents X and Y. It was all working great until recently we had problems with Internet connection on Y-end and will be getting 2 mbps download from X(speedtest.net) for the next 6 months or more. The backlog piles up each day and will be grossly unacceptable by then.

The naïve way is to copy the files (just those more urgently in need) from X onto a HDD and snail mail to Y, then copy the files manually to the local Y DFS share. But I don't think this is the correct way to do it?